# Detect Near-Duplicate Audio Files

Tags: audio, python, mp3, deduplication, flac

Suppose I have a few directories of somewhere around 4000 audio files, about half of which are FLAC and the other half are MP3.  Suppose I want to detect, not by tag metadata, but only by audio data, if I have any duplicate or near-duplicate audio files.  For example, suppose I have both a FLAC (lossless) and MP3 (lossy) version of the same song.  Making no assumptions about the file name, tag metadata, or even sample rate, I would like some way to detect if they are essentially the same tune.

There are plenty of things I have thought of, but they all have some kinds of problems:

- Can't compare file hashes or file sizes because the underlying audio format or tags might be different
- Can't compare the audio files' lengths since near-duplicates may not last for the exact same amount of time (they may be off from each other by very small fractions of  a second), and also because there could be other audio files of the same length
- Can't compare the raw audio data sample by sample since that wouldn't be able to detect a lossy and lossless version of the same track

I'm really not sure how to do this, or if there is any program that can do this.  Essentially, I'm looking for something like AntiDupl.NET, but for audio files instead of images.  Perhaps this can be done in Python with some kind of statistical analysis, using error as a threshold, but I'm not sure how that could be implemented.  Any program suggestions or other ideas?

Comment: Nope, you could maybe write something that uses some kind of neural net (which is what it sounds like the .NET thing does) but that's still going to be prone to error and hard to do.